# open a specific page by means of a local notification in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

question: I created a project in Ionic with the geofence plugin, by clicking on the notification that I receive when it has detected an area I want the application to run on a specific page, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to redirect the user to the page you want. Let me give you a piece of code to demonstrate it:

```js
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    let offer = JSON.parse(data.additionalData.offer);
    this.app.getActiveNav().push(OfferDetailsPage, {
        currentOffer: offer,
        displayArrow: true
    });
});
```

In this snippet whenever a notification is received, the application redirects the user in the page specified by OfferDetailsPage. This code is from Ionic 2.